# Tymon Jwtauth & Laravel - how to intercept unauthorised route and return 401 error?

Tags: laravel, tymon-jwt

I am using the Tymon JWT auth library to protect my API routes in laravel.  All is working, however when an unauthenticated API request is made, it attempts to redirect to a login route.  I would instead like to catch the unauthenticated exception and a 401 JSON response to the front end.

In regards to the code, it's more or less the same as the tutorial below:
https://www.positronx.io/laravel-jwt-authentication-tutorial-user-login-signup-api/

Any help from someone who has already achieved this would be appreciated.

Comment: send the correct 'Accept' header for JSON with the request and it will return JSON

Comment: @lagbox - you just saved me, what would have turned out to be a wasted few hours  - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send the `Accept` header as `application/json` this will cause the Exception Handler to return JSON when handling the Unauthorized Exception that the `auth` middleware will throw. You can see this in the `unauthenticated` method of `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`.

If you don't let the server know you want JSON back in some way, and there are other ways, it will assume this is a normal web request and return a redirect to the 'login' page by default.